# I find difficulties in proving that $L=\{a^k b^{3l} c^l | l>=0, k>0\}$ is not a regular language.

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language, pumping-lemma

By pumping lema, we have that for each sufficiently large $z \in L$, there exists $u, v$ and $w$ such as
 $z=uvw$, whith $|uv| \leq p$, $|v| \ge 1$ and $uv^iw \in L$, for each $i \ge 0.$
($p$ is the threshold given by PL)

When I want to find a word that doesn't respect the PL, it must have some $a$-s as a prefix, because $k >0$.
Given this impediment, I can not prove that any decomposition $u, v, w$ gives me a contradiction, because there it is always the possibility that $uv = a^j$ for some $j$ and this keeps $uv^i w$ in $L$.

What can I do?
It works with proving that only the second part of the words is not regular and this will imply that the concatenation is also not regular?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Do you mean $L = \{a^kb^{3l}c^l\}$? Your formatting is ambiguous.

Comment: Also your question states you want to prove it is regular but your details imply otherwise. Clarify...

Comment: @Stefan Hint: You can disprove this is a regular language with the Myhill-Nerode Theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: If you know that the class of regular languages is closed under the reversal operator, you can use the pumping lemma to prove that the language

$$L'=\left\{c^\ell b^{3\ell}a^k:\ell\ge 0\text{ and }k>0\right\}$$

is not regular; since $L=\left\{w^R:w\in L'\right\}$, it follows that $L$ is not regular either.

Otherwise, you can use the [Myhill-Nerode theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem) by finding an infinite $D\subseteq\{a,b,c\}^*$ such that whenever $u,v\in D$ and $u\ne v$, the words $u$ and $v$ have a distinguishing extension. If you adopt this approach, I suggest trying to find one member of $D$ for each $\ell\ge 1$.

Comment: Isn't the class of regular languages closed under set differentiation?